# Why is "VimL" rejected as a tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've used "VimL" as a tag on Stack Overflow and had it edited off.  I also use "vimscript" as a tag, and I know that's the preferred tag there.  I searched, and there are no questions on SO with "VimL" as a tag.  Surely I'm not the only person who's tried to use it.

**My question is: is there an official policy on the use of "VimL" as a tag?**

I stated my case in a comment on [VimScript or VimL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398312/vimscript-or-viml).  I'll restate it here:

There is only weak evidence for any official name for Vim's built-in scripting language.  You can read about it within Vim itself via `:h usr_41.txt`, which starts with:

*The Vim script language is used for the startup vimrc file, syntax files, and many other things.  This chapter explains the items that can be used in a Vim script.*

It goes on to make other references to "Vim scripts" and "the Vim scripting language", but that's the closest it comes to naming it.

The community tends to refer to "Vim script" and "vimscript" somewhat interchangeably.  There are only [604 questions tagged as "vimscript"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vimscript/info) on Stack Overflow, and there are no questions tagged as "VimL".  There are 9,711 questions tagged as "vim", many of which are about programming in "Vim script", but most of which are just about using Vim.

While "VimL" has its detractors, I think the strongest case in favor of using it is that it is unambiguous: there is nothing else named VimL out there, and it refers to *writing scripts in the Vim language*, rather than the ambiguous term "Vim script", searches for which tend to turn up many false positives on writing shell/Ruby/Perl/Python/etc. "scripts" using Vim.

"VimL" is a recent term, but its usage is being expanded largely due to GitHub labeling Vim scripting code as such; its syntax highlighting and syntax detection systems use the term.  You can see a [list of VimL projects there](https://github.com/languages/VimL).  The community is slowly adopting it elsewhere (blogs, questions on other sites).

Within Stack Overflow, the "vimscript" (single word) tag is fairly unambiguous and easy to search for, but "vimscript" is never used in any of Vim's own documentation either, and is no more or less official than "VimL".

I'll concede that this is not a strong case in favor of adding a tag, and would possibly create even more confusion (do I tag as "vimscript", "viml", or both?).  It seems likely that usage of the term "VimL" is going to increase, however, and I don't think that it's Stack Overflow's role to be the arbiter here, since there's no official name in the first place.

Comment: I just stumbled across your question, but shouldn't you in that just add it as a synonym http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vimscript/synonyms

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the synonym system.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly a case where we want a synonym.  The existing tag already covers the subject, which is why I initially nuked the new one.  Having multiple tags for the same thing, even under different terminology, is bad.

Comment: This sounds like a fine solution to my concern.  I wasn't aware of the synonym system until @DavidMulder pointed it out.  I tried to add it, but it looks like the tag needs to be on a question in order to suggest synonyms.  I can probably fake this out by re-tagging my own question for a minute.

Comment: @JimStewart: Just don't ragequit and give Charles all your rep.